# How to get default selected value using XPath

Tags: xpath, dropdown, listitem

I am trying to get the default selected value from a dropdown list. There are no Options or Values in the HTML code that I can see when I inspect the code.

[This is what the screen looks like when the user enters it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MAET.png)
 If you click the dropdown, you will see that the [value 8 is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckN2T.png) because it is the default value

The HTML code does not show the value 8 anywhere nor any of the other values listed that can be selected. I need to verify that the default value is 8 but I'm having a hard time finding the correct code to do this.

[This is the html:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3nCh.png)

I can use this Xpath to click on the dropdown button: 
//*[contains(@class,'label')][text()='Minimum Length']/ancestor::*/following-sibling::*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MAET.png)//*[@role='combobox']//*[contains(@class,'filterselect-button')][@role='button']

This will also click on the combo box and allow the dropdown list to appear
//*[text()='${Name}']/parent::*/following-sibling::*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MAET.png)//*[contains(@type,'text')]

Comment: Website might be dynamically rendered. Can you post the website URL ? Screenshots with code aren't allowed on SO.

Comment: It isn't a website that you would be able to get to. It is a product that I am testing that is web based. If the website is dynamically rendered, is there a way for me to get the value?

Comment: It must be vaadin comboboxes which are dynamically rendered. Do they look the same as yours ? https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples Selenium could handle this type of website.

Comment: I am on the test side. I don't have access to the code the developers used to create the pages. I do see that they are combo boxes in the html, but there are several nested statements under the combo box that then defines the input text and the dropdown button. However there are no values in the html

Comment: Time to use Selenium then. Once you click on the dropdown button, there must be a call to load the values and parse it in the html. Once you click out, the values are removed from the html. vaadin seems to load data in JSON format then push them in elements with "VAADIN_COMBOBOX_OPTIONLIST'" attributes.

Comment: I believe something loads when I go to the page because there is a default value of 8 that is listed there. I am trying to validate that the default is set to 8. Then if I click on the dropdown, the 8 is highlighted there. I will research further and see what method in Selenium I can use to validate that default value there. I just haven't found anything so far.

Comment: Puppeteer could also be an option. I don't use it but we could imagine : Go to Webpage>Screenshot the combobox>OCR the result with an API like :https://ocr.space/ocrapi.